# Linking files on a network drive

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

have two excels files on a network drive. Linked file path: Z:\A\ABC\a.xlsx Source file: Z:A\b.xlsx The link from source to linked cell is by clicking the appropriate reference cell in source. For e.g. Cell C9 in a.xls has

='Z:\A[b.xlsx]Sheet 1'!$C$9
Issue: Every time I open the linked excel I need to RELINK the source. The Status when I go to Data>Edit Links.. Shows as "Unknown" Can anyone let me know why I am facing the issues? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reference to the file by its network name. Lets assume that Z: is connected to the following share: test on server: myserver, your path would become

```
\\myserver\test\A\b.xlsx
```

Comment: Thanks! This works when I logon to the network directly but if I have the drive mapped then it does not. Any solutions?

Comment: Drive mapping has nothing to do with accessing the share directly.